# Show that $|X_n|\leq Y$ a.s. implies $\sup_n |X_n|\leq Y$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$, show that $|X_n|\leq Y$ a.s. implies $\sup_n |X_n|\leq Y$ a.s.

Here is my attempt:

$|X_n|\leq Y$ a.s. means that $P(|X_n|>Y)=0$, $\forall n\geq 1$

$P(\sup_n |X_n|>Y)\leq P(\bigcup_n [|X_n|>Y])\leq \sum_n P(|X_n|>Y)=0 $

This implies $P(\sup_n |X_n|>Y)=0$.

Is this rigorous enough of a proof?

Comment: I think it is a fair proof.

Comment: That is okay. In the essential line the first $\leq$ can be replaced by an equality sign, but that is of inferior interest.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version of your proof below. Maybe it helps some others.

Note that $\sup_n \lvert X_n\rvert \leq Y $ almost surely if and only if $ \lvert X_n\rvert \leq Y $ for all $n$ almost surely.

We have $ \lvert X_n\rvert \leq Y $ almost surely  for all $n$.

Define $\Omega_n := \{X_n \leq Y\}$ and $\Omega := \{\lvert X_n\rvert \leq Y \text{ for all } n\}$. Note that $\Omega =  \cap_n \Omega_n$. Since the intersection of countably many full measure sets has full measure, $P(\Omega) = 1$.